# Node js. sending an html that contains an image

Tags: html, node.js

I have built a simple server using node js.
I wish to send an html that contains an image inside.

Ok, so i know how to send back an html file.
And i know how to send back an image.

When i send the html response with the `<img src = 'green2.jpg'>` in it, 
the page loads with a broken image.

Any ideas?

Relevant code :

```
var net = require ('net');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('server disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        get();
    });

    var get = function (parse) {
        fs.readFile('example.html',  function(err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            socket.write('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nDate: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n');
            socket.write(data);
            socket.end();
        });
    }
});

server.listen("8888");
```

Comment: Probably just your image path broken, nothing to do with node.js.

Comment: When i open the html file it loads fine

Comment: How are your routes setup? Meaning, how does the server know what to return based on the users request.

Comment: Your problem isn't example.html its that you can't go to http://localhost:YOURPORT/green2.jpg

Comment: @oopsi you need to share the rest of your server code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current code is saying this:

*Anytime I get any request, send down the contents of example.html.*

If someone asks for /whatever.jpg they're going to get the contents of example.html which of course will show you a broken image.

If you want to server up static files using node.js you'll want to probably use something like [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) which handles it automatically using the `express.static` middleware referenced here:
http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use

Obviously "use express" isn't an answer to your question, but the answer to your question using pure node.js is either one of the following:

1. Install a module like node-static to handle static files like images. [Tutorial here](http://www.sitepoint.com/serving-static-files-with-node-js/)
2. Use a switch statement on `req.url` to figure our which file the server is looking for and send it down using something similar to your `fs.readFile('example.html')`, but that could also read an image file.

Comment: Awesome answer. Made me realize more than i hoped. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that node isn't aware of your image and can't serve static files out-of-the-box like your average web server. Using a framework like [express](http://expressjs.com/) makes this much easier.